# Знак препинания перед словом "неизвестно"

Tags: пунктуация

За последний год всё чаще возникают ситуации, где устанавливаются задачи на несколько лет вперёд, но как добиться успеха и строить планы, когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы, неизвестно.

Comment: А Ваши варианты?

Comment: ПС Я ориентируюсь на ваш исходный текст, с вопросительным знаком. Запятую вам поставили при правке, у вас, как понимаю, сомнения.

Answer (score 2):

*За последний год всё чаще возникают ситуации, где устанавливаются задачи на несколько лет вперёд, но как добиться успеха и строить планы, когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы, неизвестно.*

Структура предложения не кажется мне достаточно корректной и обоснованной, поэтому сложно выбрать и знак препинания, да и прочесть его затруднительно. Почему?  В данном случае выбрана **неудачная позиция** для слова «неизвестно», так как его лучше перенести в середину фразы:

*За последний год всё чаще возникают ситуации, где  устанавливаются задачи на несколько лет вперёд, но **неизвестно**, как добиться успеха и строить планы, когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы.*

**Пояснение**

1. Если мы располагаем «неизвестно» в конце предложения, то его надо обособлять **тире.** Тире – неосновной знак для сложноподчиненного предложения, и эту тему с примерами можно посмотреть у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142
   Например: *Что он человек знающий — **факт**; Появились какие-то новые слухи о нём, но какие — **неизвестно**.*
2. Это как раз наш случай: **изъяснительные отношения и разная структура предложений**.  Мы могли бы поставить тире в таком предложении: *Как добиться успеха и строить планы – **неизвестно**.*  Также тире можно поставить, если у нас **однородные** отношения между придаточными, например: Кругом люди, и *кто зачем пришёл, у кого какое дело — неясно.*
3. Но в заданном предложении однородных отношений между придаточными нет (там последовательное подчинение придаточных)  – поэтому второе придаточное нужно **закрыть запятой**, тогда получается сочетание знаков «запятая и тире». И вот это создает проблемы: вариант неудачно смотрится и читается непонятно как. Поэтому такая грамматика просто **не используется**.
4. **Примечание.** Есть, правда, вариант  **с отсутствием закрывающей запятой**: «…*но как добиться успеха и строить планы, когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы – неизвестно»*.  Но такой вариант  (ввиду распространенности предложений) тоже сложно прочитать и понять, а **оспорить легко**. Пропуск закрывающей запятой встречается в реальных текстах, но его пока приходится считать ненормированным, так как правилами он не закреплен.
5. **Ну и зачем такие проблемы**? Легче перенести слово «неизвестно» в середину фразы.

Answer (score 0):

> За последний год всё чаще возникают ситуации, где устанавливаются
> задачи на несколько лет вперёд, но как добиться успеха и строить
> планы, когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы (?)
> неизвестно.

Ваши сомнения тут непонятны. Запятая там нужна уже потому, что закрывает придаточное "когда новые тренды и тенденции вносят свои коррективы". Или у вас сомнения другого плана?

Тут скорее может возникнукть вопрос о запятой перед "как".